# Get Table Columns With Primary Key Constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all the columns (MSSQL SERVER) of a particular Table Along with whether it is _PK or Not. So far I have Tried:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG AS Database_Name, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

And its Out Put is:

```
Database_Name   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME IS_NULLABLE
-------------   ------------    ----------  ----------- -----------
```

Now I want one More Column to above Table Say 'IS_PRIMARYKEY', means I want the output as:

```
 Database_Name  TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME IS_NULLABLE IS_PRIMARYKEY
 -------------  ------------    ----------  ----------- ----------- -------------
```

How ths can be Achieved in One Query/Procedure ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to join on `information_schema.key_column_usage`.

Comment: yes, I have tried that join, but could not get desired output

Comment: PLEASE REFER TO MY ANSWER BELOW AND MARK IT AS ANSWER IF IT SERVES YOUR PURPOSE...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONSTRAINT DATA IS STORED IN DIFFERENT TABLES HENCE YOU NEED TO APPLY A JOIN TO MATCH TABLE CONSTRAINT AND COLUMN USAGE CONSTRAINT TO GET THE PRIMARY KEY COLUMN.

BUT SINCE YOU NEED THE DETAILS IN A SINGLE QUERY, I HAVE CREATED A ALIAS OF MY QUERY TO GENERATE THE DESIRED OUTPUT. BELOW QUERY WILL GIVE YOU APPROPRIATE ANSWER.

CANNOT CREATE FIDDLE AS THIS IS ONLY HAVING SYSTEM TABLES.

I HAVE DONE THIS FOR MY TEMP TABLE tbl_primaryKey YOU CAN REPLACE THE TABLE NAME AS PER YOUR NEED.

```
SELECT Database_Name,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,IS_NULLABLE, CASE WHEN (IS_PRIMARYKEY IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE 'YES' END AS [IS_PRIMARYKEY]
FROM 

(SELECT cols.TABLE_CATALOG AS Database_Name, cols.TABLE_SCHEMA, cols.TABLE_NAME, cols.COLUMN_NAME, cols.IS_NULLABLE, 

(SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = 'tbl_primaryKey'
    AND cols.COLUMN_NAME = Col.COLUMN_NAME
    ) AS IS_PRIMARYKEY
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
WHERE
cols.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_primaryKey' ) A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT TABLE_CATALOG AS Database_Name, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, if(COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI', 'YES', 'NO') AS IS_PRIMARYLEY 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

You can do this by using If condition, for number's of Columns use *

Comment: It shows error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.'